# Making an index of a book with XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a XML with the following structure where I wanna make an index of some specific words:

```
<book>
<chapter title="This is first chapter">
        <section title="This is the first section">
        <paragraph title="This is the first paragraph">This is the paragraph content, where this <index>word</index> should be in the index</paragraph>
        </section>
</chapter>
<chapter title="This is second chapter">
        <section title="This is the first section">
        <paragraph title="This is the first paragraph">This is the paragraph content</paragraph>
        </section>
</chapter>
</book>
```

So, I wanna make a list of all `<index>` elements, and here is what I tried:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="book/chapter" />
</xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="chapter">
            <html>
            <head>
                <title>Index</title>
            </head>
            <body>
      <h1>
            Index
        </h1>
        <xsl:apply-templates  />
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="index">
    <p> 
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </p>
   </xsl:template>
```

So, all the words are printed correctly, but the problem is that all the text from the XML is printed as well in a mess (all textnodes are printed after each other). I only want the index elements, and nothing else.

Comment: You want just a simple list of all indexed words, in document order? With no indication of their location? (or sorting, or grouping of duplicates)?

Comment: The reason you're getting all of the text nodes is because of XSLTs built-in rules (http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#built-in-rule). Try adding the template `<xsl:template match="text()"/>`.

Comment: @user3016153 I will order it, but that will probably be another question later.

Comment: @DanielHaley Worked! And thanks a lot for the insight! Add it as an answer if you'd like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you're getting all of the text nodes is because of [XSLTs built-in rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#built-in-rule).

Try adding the template:

```
<xsl:template match="text()"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I think you need *less* templates, not more:

```
<xsl:template match="/book">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Index</h1>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::index"/>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="index">
    <p><xsl:value-of select="."/></p>
</xsl:template>
```

Or, if you prefer:

```
<xsl:template match="/book">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Index</h1>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::index" >
        <xsl:sort select="." data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates >
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="index">
    <p><xsl:value-of select="."/></p>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: This actually works perfectly! Thanks for the sorting. Is there an easy way to merge similar elements, and add the chapter and paragraph position for the specific occurencies of that specific indexed word? Like for example 'word - 2.5, 3.1, 4.2'. Guess I should make a new question for that?

Comment: @janlindso Are you familiar with [Muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html)?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a rough attempt to produce a *real* index - i.e. grouped, sorted and including a list of locations where each entry is found (in the form of chapter#.paragraph#).

Some assumptions are being made here:

- Your processor supports the EXSLT set:distinct() function (thus avoiding the need for Muenchian grouping);

  All index entries appear within a paragraph element (although not necessarily as a direct child); each index entry appears only once in the same paragraph;

  All paragraphs are children of a section; all sections are children of a chapter.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:set="http://exslt.org/sets"
extension-element-prefixes = "set">
<xsl:output method="html" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="index" match="index" use="." />

<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Index</h1>

    <xsl:for-each select="set:distinct(book/chapter/section/paragraph//index)">
    <xsl:sort select="." data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
    <p>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:text> - </xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each select="key('index', .)">
            <xsl:value-of select="count(ancestor::chapter/preceding-sibling::chapter) + 1"/>
            <xsl:text>.</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="count(ancestor::paragraph/preceding-sibling::paragraph) + count(ancestor::section/preceding-sibling::section/paragraph) + 1"/>
            <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>   
        </xsl:for-each>
    </p>
    </xsl:for-each>  
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

With the appropriate `apply-template` select, and I added the chapter title into the index headings.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="book/chapter" />
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="chapter">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Index</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <h1><xsl:value-of select="@title"/> Index</h1>
        <xsl:apply-templates select=".//index"  />
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="text()">
    <p> 
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </p>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```